# Adaptive HID headlights not working after rain intake due to a crack in the housing from an impact. Can anything be salvaged or repaired?

Tags: headlight, buick, hid, lesabre

I have a '13 Buick Lacrosse with a touring trim. It comes with adaptive HID headlights with a blue rings (whatever it is, it's very hard to find).

There is a rather large crack in the polycarbonate casing from an impact which unfortunately happened same day it was raining, so I am guessing the headlight is burned out.

Dealership is asking $1,300 for the headlight assembly. Finding used headlight assembly with that blue ring is a tall order and apparently they are all slightly different. There is one on car-part.com but it's very far and they don't ship it.

What's the best course of action for me? Does the water cause all parts to break or just the burn out the bulb? Could I replace the burned out bulb and patch up the crack with a strong epoxy glue or something similar?

Headlight in question:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!